# Skip some worksheets in loop function in Excel VBA

Tags: excel

I want to have a button replace the info on MOST sheets with the info from a master sheet when a button is clicked. However, I want it to skip some sheets.

I have the below code that works, but there are 2 sheets I want it to skip when running. How can I specify that is skip the sheets named "Dates" and "Monthly"

```
 Sub Button4_Click()

 Dim wsVar As Worksheet

 For Each wsVar In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
     With wsVar
        .Range("B9:M30").Value = Worksheets("BASE").Range("B9:M30").Value
     End With
 Next wsVar

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an IF statement to check the name of the worksheet and then act accordingly.

```
   For Each wsVar In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
     If wsVar.Name = "foo" Or wsVar.Name = "bar" Then
      ' do nothing
     Else
    
        With wsVar
            .Range("B9:M30").Value = Worksheets("BASE").Range("B9:M30").Value
        End With
    
     End If
   Next wsVar
```

Comment: Where in my code would the If statement go?

Comment: I added some sample code. Adjust the foo and bar to the sheets you want to skip.

Comment: That's the ticket! Thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: It has to be a certain amount of time after it's asked

Answer (score 0):

This code will exclude all sheets listed in the `Exclude` array. Note that sheets name comparisons are carried out case-insensitive and leading or trailing blanks are deemed unintentional and removed.

```
Sub Button4_Click()

    Dim wsVar       As Worksheet
    Dim Exclude()   As String
    Dim i           As Integer
    
    Exclude = Split("Dates,Monthly", ",")
    For Each wsVar In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With wsVar
            For i = UBound(Exclude) To 0 Step -1
                If StrComp(wsVar.Name, Trim(Exclude(i))) = 0 Then Exit For
            Next i
            If i >= 0 Then .Range("B9:M30").Value = Worksheets("BASE").Range("B9:M30").Value
        End With
    Next wsVar

 End Sub
```

With a small change, you might convert this same function to process only listed sheets. To identify sheets for action positively, rather than negatively, is the safe way, generally speaking. But if you decide to do that, please also do rename the array :-)